# C++ Header To Source?

Tags: c++

I'm programming in C++ CLI with VS.Net C++ 2008. I'm seeking a tool that can create my C++ source definitions (*.cpp) from the header files. Does such a tool exist? please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pure C++ code, if its possible to add a 3rd party generator to the VS.Net frame work, then I would strongly recommend: [lzz](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/).

This tools takes a text file as input, and will provide a header and source file for you as appropriate.  The following is the basic example from the web page:

> ```
> // A.lzz
> class A
> {
> public:
>   inline void f (int i) { ... }
>   void g (int j = 0) { ... }
> };
> bool operator == (A const & a1, A const & a2) { ... }
> ```
>
> Lzz will generate a header file:
>
> ```
> // A.h
> #ifndef LZZ_A_h
> #define LZZ_A_h
> class A
> {
> public:
>   void f (int i);
>   void g (int j = 0);
> };
> inline void A::f (int i) { ... }
> bool operator == (A const & a1, A const & a2);
> #endif
> ```
>
> And a source file:
>
> ```
> // A.cpp
> #include "A.h"
> void A::g (int j) { ... }
> bool operator == (A const & a1, A const & a2) { ... }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Code::Blocks IDE seems to have a "Insert / All class methods without Implementation" method
which generates some basic skeleton of the functions.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm seeking a tool that can create my C++ source definitions (*.cpp) from the header files.

Do you mean: How do I copy the function signatures? Because, I wouldn't want a program to define any functions for me. Who want's to lose a job now ;)

Anyway, you can define your own macro for the IDE if you want to copy signatures.